# Erro na hora de incluir dados utilizando Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, dbeaver

Estou recebendo a mensagem de erro abaixo ao tentar inserir um novo dado no BD a partir de uma aplicacap Flask:

```
ArgumentError sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column type VARCHAR(100) on column 'turma.nome' is not compatible with autoincrement=True
```

A "turma.nome" representa uma linha da minha tabela que e' do tipo VARCHAR(100) e pelo DBeaver, a unica coluna que possiu autoincremento e' a "id".

Alguem saberia a causa do erro?